# How do I cut objects in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have created a document in Illustrator that consists of a background object (the blue part) and many small green objects ("bushes"). Please see an image below:

[image]

What I want is to cut the lower part of the "bushes" to make it look like this:

[image]

How do I do this in Illustrator?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with a clipping mask in Illustrator:

A clipping mask:

- Create a box over your image:

[image]

Select both the box and the image and go to `Object -> Clipping Mask -> Make`:

[image]

---

If the circles are vector I would merge the layer then use the pathfinder tool:

Hightlight the circles:

[image]

`Pathfinder -> Unite`:

[image]

Create the box you want to cut on top of the shape:

[image]

Select both and go to `Pathfinder -> Minus Front`:

[image]